# Finding smallest vector satisfying an equation with a dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, products

I was wondering whether you could help me understand a solution to one of the problems from the *6.036 Introduction to Machine Learning* from *MIT Open Learning Library*. The task is to find the smallest vector (with respect to the L2 norm) $\theta$ which satisfies the equation

$$\theta \cdot x = \frac{1}{y}$$

where $x$ is an arbitrary vector (with the same dimension as $\theta$), y is a constant taking either value $+1$ or $-1$ and $\cdot$ is the dot product.

The provided solution is:

$$\theta = \frac{x}{\| x \|^2} \times \frac{1}{y}$$

Even after looking at the solution, I am still not sure how this problem was supposed to be solved. It seems that the solution could be derived using manipulations similar to:

1. $\theta \times (x \cdot x) = x \times {1 \over y}$
2. $\theta \times \| x \| ^ 2 = x \times {1 \over y}$
3. $\theta = {x \over \| x \| ^ 2} \times {1 \over y}$

However, I struggle to see what could be the justification for transforming the original equation to the form in the first step, so I suspect this might not be the right way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$ \theta \cdot x = | \theta | | x | \cos \psi = \dfrac{1}{y}$

where $\psi$ is the angle between the vector $x$ and the vector $\theta$.

Since $x$ and $y$ are fixed, this implies the minimum $| \theta |$ occurs when

$\cos \psi $ is maximum, and this occurs when $\psi = 0$ so that $\cos \psi = 1$.

And with this, $\theta$ will be aligned with $x$ , i.e. along $x$.

Thus $\theta = \alpha x$ , for a certain $\alpha \gt 0$ that we're about to find.

Plug this expression for $\theta$ in the original equation, you get,

$\theta \cdot x = \alpha x \cdot x = \dfrac{1}{y} $

Hence $\alpha = \dfrac{1}{x \cdot x } \times \dfrac{1}{y} $

Finally we note that $x \cdot x = | x |^2 $

This gives the answer mentioned in the lecture.

Comment: Hi @Robin’sPremiumCoffee please could you help out with https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4445701/585488

Answer (score 3):

GeometryLover's solution is the way that I would solve the problem; it captures the geometric intuition behind the solution and can easily be made fully rigorous.

I want to point out, though, that it's also possible to brute-force the solution by solving the optimization problem exactly as stated, which might prove useful for other, less simple problem of similar flavor:

We are asked to solve

$$\min_{\theta} \|\theta\|^2 \quad \mathrm{s.t.}\quad \theta \cdot x = \frac{1}{y}.$$

This is a convex quadratic program whose unique solution can be found using the method of Lagrange multipliers: the constrained problem is equivalent to

$$\operatorname{ext}_{\theta,\lambda}  \|\theta\|^2 - \lambda\left(\theta\cdot x - \frac{1}{y}\right)$$
whose optimality conditions are
\begin{align*}
2\theta - \lambda x &= 0\\
\theta \cdot x - \frac{1}{y} &= 0.
\end{align*}
The first equations gives you $\theta = \lambda x/2$, and all we need to do is to find $\lambda$, which we can do by plugging into the second equation:
$$\frac{\lambda \|x\|^2}{2} - \frac{1}{y} = 0$$
or
$$\lambda = \frac{2}{y\|x\|^2}$$
which gives
$$\theta = \frac{x}{y\|x\|^2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

It may be useful to know that if $x$ is a fixed vector and $h$ is a constant,
a plane in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space with an origin is defined by
the set of position vectors $\theta$ that satisfy

$$ \theta \cdot x = h. $$

The plane defined in this way is perpendicular to the vector $x$ and is at
the distance $\lvert h\rvert/\lVert x\rVert$ from the origin.

Given a point $P$ (in this case, given the origin) and a plane,
the point on the given plane closest to the given point $P$ is at the base of the perpendicular line dropped from $P$ to the plane.
In the case of the plane defined by $ \theta \cdot x = h, $
that perpendicular line is the line in the direction of $x.$

This tells us that the shortest $\theta$ lies along that same line,
either exactly in the direction of $x$ or exactly opposite.
That is, the solution is $\theta = r x$ for some scalar factor $r.$

With $h = 1/y$ and $y = \pm 1,$ you have $h = 1$ if $y=1$ and $h = -1$ if $y = -1.$
In either case $\lvert h\vert = 1,$ so the plane defined when $h = 1$
and the plane defined when $h = -1$ are the same distance from the origin.
We therefore have two shortest vectors, one of length $1/\lVert x\rVert$
in the direction of $x$ and one of length $1/\lVert x\rVert$
in the direction exactly opposite to $x$.

Those two vectors are
$$ \frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert^2} x $$
and
$$ -\frac{1}{\lVert x\rVert^2} x, $$

which can also be written
$$ \frac1y\left( \frac{x}{\lVert x\rVert^2} \right)$$
for $y = 1$ or $y = -1.$